# Стоит ли использовать библиотеки Http запросов для Android?

Tags: java, android, http

Стоит ли их использовать новичкам, решат ли они кучу проблем для новичков как допустим это делает библиотека для изображений Picasso? Проекты у новичков не сложные, но хочется чтоб все было правильно. Если использовать библиотеки Http-запросов, то какую использовать по критериям простота/эффективность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотеками вообще нужно пользоваться , их для того и пишут . Это избавляет от рутинной работы по реализации вспомогательного функционала и страхует от ошибок при этой реализации . Как правило известная библиотека вылизана до мелочей и вряд ли вы сами напишите лучше .

наиболее популярные http библиотеки Android( помимо так же весьма популярной OkHttp ):

1. https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http
2. https://github.com/square/retrofit
3. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
   ( зеркало на github https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley )

Answer (score 1):

От тех же ребят, что сделали Picasso - [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). Весьма удобная штука. 2 часа чтения мануалов и даже самый новый новичок разберется как этим пользоваться:) Проблем в использовании никогда не вызывало, лично у меня.
И...да, безусловно стоит. Не стоит новичкам изобретать свои велосипеды, да и квалификации не хватит.